# How to add an image URL Path in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a front end page. Please let me know how to add the URL for WordPress and how to add CSS for the background image?

My image html element

1. `<img src="./img/Hbook.jpg" class="img-responsive">`
2. background-image selectors

```
.firstSection{
    background-image: url("../img/car.png"); 
        margin-top:0px; 
        background-size:cover;
        background-position:50%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height:800px; 
        display: table; 
        width: 100%;
        
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-image property inline-css in the php file to set wordpress image url. You can do code like this.

```
<?php $image = 'pathto/image'; ?>

<section class="firstSection" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image; ?>);">
    <img src="./img/Hbook.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</section>
```